# React Native FBSDKPackage linking error on react native 0.60 version because of PackageList auto generated file

Tags: android, react-native

> React Native FBSDKPackage linking error on react native 0.60 version
>   because of PackageList auto generated file.

public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {

```
  private static final String TAG = "MainApplication";



  private static CallbackManager mCallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

  protected static CallbackManager getCallbackManager() {
    return mCallbackManager;
  }



  private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost = new ReactNativeHost(this) {
    @Override
    public boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
      return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
    }

    @Override
    protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
      @SuppressWarnings("UnnecessaryLocalVariable")
      List<ReactPackage> packages = new PackageList(this).getPackages();
      packages.add(new FBSDKPackage(mCallbackManager));
      packages.add(new RNGoogleSigninPackage());
      packages.add(new Interactable());
      // Packages that cannot be autolinked yet can be added manually here, for example:
      // packages.add(new MyReactNativePackage());
      return packages;
    }

    @Override
    protected String getJSMainModuleName() {
      return "index";
    }
  };

  @Override
  public ReactNativeHost getReactNativeHost() {
    return mReactNativeHost;
  }
```

> AutoGenerated Packages

```
 private Context getApplicationContext() {
    return this.getApplication().getApplicationContext();
  }

  public ArrayList<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
    return new ArrayList<>(Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
      new MainReactPackage(),
      new FBSDKPackage(),
      new RNGoogleSigninPackage()
    ));
  }
```

> Error

error: constructor FBSDKPackage in class FBSDKPackage cannot be applied to given types
required: CallbackManager
found: no arguments
    reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Comment: Can you add the error that you are facing?

Comment: error: constructor FBSDKPackage in class FBSDKPackage cannot be applied to given types;
required: CallbackManager
found: no arguments
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Comment: You need to remove mCallbakManager, refer https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk/pull/576

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> Instead of this npm install react-native-fbsdk
> installed this it worked
> ```
>
> npm install git+https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk.git

Answer (score 0):

You can change

```
new FBSDKPackage(mCallbackManager)
```

to

```
new FBSDKPackage()
```

I mean remove the `mCallbackManager`

Refer the [solution](https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk/pull/576)

Comment: packages.add(new FBSDKPackage(mCallbackManager)); already added

Comment: I have updated the answer and ref. link as well, please check now.

Comment: Note this applies if you're using v1.x, which is currently in RC. If you're still on v0.10.x, `mCallbackManager` is still required.

Answer (score 0):

I have found weird solution. Using the stable fbsdk version `1.0.1` I keep getting error:

```
PackageList.java:68: error: constructor FBSDKPackage in class FBSDKPackage cannot be applied to given types;
      new FBSDKPackage(),
      ^
 required: CallbackManager
 found: no arguments
```

BUT with `1.0.0-rc.4` it suddenly disappears. They have propably some bug in stable version.